# SSAS Cubes processes on local machine but not on server

Tags: ssas, cube

I am new to SSAS. Probably there is a simple answer for my problems but I can't figure it out. We had a ransomware attack on our server that ruined all the data.

Me and my colleague restored the data on server and tried to reprocess all the dimensions and Cubes but we were getting  A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'xyz', Name of 'XYZ Data'.

We were also getting the error stating
Internal error: An unexpected error occurred (file 'pfcre.cpp', line 1234, function 'PFCREngine::SelectCartridge').

We tried testing the connection by right clicking on the Datasource from SSMS, properties, connection string, Test Connection. It was connecting to the data source successfully.

We then restored the database on our local machine and tried processing the data. This time it did process all the dimensions and cubes. So, we tried taking the backup of our local database, restore it in the server. Again the database on server wouldn't process it even though admin would try to process it. We are still getting the A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'xyz', Name of 'XYZ Data' error.

So, for now we have to manually process the data base on our local machine everyday , backup that to restore it on server, so that users can run the reports to get the fresh data.

Your help will be highly appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: What impersonation information is used in the connection to the data source?  And if it's an account does the account have the proper permissions on the server/database where the source data is located?

Comment: On local machine -  Checking at Datasource level it says Inherit. At Database level it says Default and at Instance level in the security tab I see local admin user added.
We have a role named 'ArchDesigner' with Full control and in memberships I see some system created GUID listed.

Comment: On Server - At Datasource level it says Inherit. At Database level it says Default and at Instance level in the security tab I see  Corp\Admin , corp\myuseraccount and couple system created GUID added. Also there are two users listed with corp\sqlservice and corp\analservice names
We have a role named 'ArchDesigner' with Full control and in memberships I see some system created GUID listed.